# SSH while-loop in bash. Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal

Tags: bash, while-loop, pty, stty

I am trying to loop a file to ssh to a list of servers, and perform a find command on those servers for certain logfiles. I know that ssh will swallow the input file as a whole. So i am using the -n parameter to ssh. This works fine but oncertain servers i encounter a new error.

The input file is build like:
servername:location:mtime:logfileexention

The code in Bash I use is:

```
sshCmd="ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o Batchmode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q"

while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 ; do        
$sshCmd "$f1"
find "$f2" -type f -name "$f4" -mtime +"$f3"
```

On certain servers i receive the following error:

**Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device**

I have tried multiple options to resolve this. I have used the -t, -tt, -T options but when using these either the same error persists or the terminal becomes unresponsive.

Anyone has a solution for this?

Comment: Consider using Ansible or Puppet Bolt for tasks like this.

Comment: @brunorey that is no option atm

Comment: `sshCmd` should be a function, not a variable.

Comment: Is the `find` command supposed to run on the remote host? As shown, you are trying to start an interactive shell (the default command).

Comment: @chepner that sshCmd is not a function will not resolve the issue. I want to perform the find on the remote machine. Ssh'ing into a remote machine would be useless if the find would need to perform locally.

Comment: I never said it would resolve the issue; never the less, it *should* be a function. See [Bash FAQ 050](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). And since `find` has to be run on the remote machine, you need to specify it as an actual argument *to* `ssh`, not written as a separate command on the following line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running `find` on the remote host; you are trying to run a login shell on the remote host, and only after that exits would `find` run. Further, the remote shell fails because its standard input was redirected from `/dev/null` due to the `-n` option.

```
sshCmd="ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o Batchmode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no -o PasswordAuthentication=no -q"

while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 ; do   
  # Beware of values for f2, f3, and f4 containing double quotes themselves.     
  $sshCmd "$f1" "find \"$f2\" -type f -name \"$f4\" -mtime +\"$f3\""
done
```

---

Unrelated, but `sshCmd` should be a *function*, not a variable to expand.

```
sshCmd () {
  ssh -n -o ConnectTimeout=5 -o Batchmode=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o CheckHostIP=no -q "$@"
}

while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4; do
   sshCmd "$f1" "find \"$f2\" -type f -name \"$f4\" -mtime +\"$f3\""
done
```

Comment: This work with 1 exception. When i ssh to an SunOS machine i still get the following error:

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Oracle Corporation      SunOS 5.10      Generic Patch   January 2005

When i leave the -n option i can ssh but it will break the function for the while loop. Any suggestion? @chepner

Comment: What happens if you use `-T` is explicitly disable pseudo-terminal allocation?

Comment: Seems like the input file was not correct for that specific server. So the original solutions still applies and works. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Minor addition: save yourself some backslash grief:

```
while IFS=: read -r f1 f2 f3 f4; do
   sshCmd "$f1" "find '$f2' -type f -name '$f4' -mtime +'$f3'"
done
```

Everything inside the double quotes will be expanded prior to command processing, so the values will be expanded, and sitting inside single quotes, for the remote host to handle; i.e. the remote host will see the values, and not the variable names.

(Standard disclaimer applies regarding the possibility of f1, f2, f3, f4 containing single quotes...)